# Unsigned char to hexstring and back but results don't match

Tags: c, char, unsigned

I have an unsigned char array c1 of length 32.

```
unsigned char c1[32]
```

Now I have an encryption function, details of which are lengthy.Basically this encryption just puts in some value into c1.

```
encrypt(&c1,private_key,public_key,message);
```

Now I have the following code to convert it into hex string:

```
printf("Initial value is %02x",c1);
char *sit = malloc(sizeof c1 * 2 + 1);
     for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof c1; i++)
     { sprintf(sit + i * 2, "%02x", c1[i]);
       
     }
```

Now I try to get the unsigned char array back:

```
unsigned char recvalue[32];
     for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
          {
             unsigned testchar=0;
             sscanf(&sit[i*2],"%02x",&testchar);
             recvalue[i]=(unsigned char)testchar;
          }
printf("The final value is %02x",recvalue);
```

Now the value of c1 and recvalue here does not match but I need them to match. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `i < sizeof c1` That doesn't look right. `sizeof c1` is the size of the array in bytes (assuming it is an actual array and not a dynamic memory buffer) and not the number of entries in the array. For further help please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're not providing the definitions for some variables that will affect how this code runs.  What is `c1` (in 1st block)?  What is `sit` (in 2nd block, don't want to assume it's the same as 1st block)?

Comment: @kaylum I don't get how does it matter. Because in char arrays, the size is the same as number of bytes.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't know what you mean. I have clearly defined and allocated memory for the variable sit. I have also clearly mentioned c1 is an unsigned char array of length 32.

Comment: That's true. But it isn't clear from the code as you do not show the definition. Please provide complete code as requested. And please read the link if you feel the urge to question why that is needed.

Comment: The `printf` statements don't print the contents of the arrays.  They just print the address of each.  You need to loop through them.

Comment: @kaylum I cannot write the details of the encryption function here because that would be like 2 pages. I hope after the edit, my question is very clear.

Comment: `printf("The final value is %02x",&recvalue);` I believe you meant `*recvalue` not `&recvalue`. Also yeah as @dbush pointed out if you intent to print the entire thing you need a loop.

Comment: @Havenard Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the code in the question. The two values still don't match though.

Comment: It's still not right. Compare `*recvalue` and "loop through each item" with what you have. Same for `c1` print.

Comment: @ArnabGhosh And they shouldn't match because you're printing the addresses of two separate arrays (and incorrectly at that).  You want to loop through each one and print the contents.

Comment: `*recvalue` not just `recvalue`. `*recvalue` is the same as `recvalue[0]`. It's an array, so you need to pull elements out of it otherwise you're passing it as a pointer and it will print weird stuff.

Comment: Use a debugger.  `sizeof` not working as you expect.  Don't get fancy, use a const int or #define.

Comment: @kaylum If I do 
```
printf("The final value is %02x",*recvalue);
```
It just prints one byte which I assume is the address.

Comment: Exactly. Which is wrong. You: `recvalue`, comments `*recvalue`. Isn't the difference obvious? You need to print the value in the array not try to print the array address. Why would comparing the array addresses be useful?

Comment: @Havenard Ok wait . I get what you're trying to say. I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: @ArnabGhosh what exactly are you expecting to happen when you try and copy 2 bytes from `sit` into an address that points to a single byte?  (`&testchar`)?

Comment: Your program does work correctly, you are just not displaying the end result properly

Comment: @Havenard You were right. Thanks so much for catching this novice mistake. I accepted the first answer but your comment is the actual thing which helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%02x` (or `%02X`) format in `printf` prints at least two digits of the provided integer. It is like a `%u`, but will print the value given in hexadecimal base instead. However, you're giving it the address of an array.
It seems you're confusing it with the `%s` format, for which you actually give the initial address of a string and it will print the whole string.
`%02x` is different. It requires a integer value.
Index the array so you will be giving it actual byte values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c1[32] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                            0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00,
                            0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18,
                            0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20 };

    char *sit = malloc(sizeof c1 * 2 + 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof c1; i++)
    {
        sprintf(sit + i * 2, "%02x", c1[i]);
    }

    printf("Initial value is: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof c1; i++)
        printf("%02X ", c1[i]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("sit is: %s\n", sit);

    unsigned char recvalue[32];
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
       unsigned testchar=0;
       sscanf(&sit[i*2],"%02x",&testchar);
       recvalue[i]=(unsigned char)testchar;
    }

    printf("The final value is: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof recvalue; i++)
        printf("%02X ", recvalue[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial value is: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20  
sit is: 0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f001112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f20
The final value is: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20
```

Comment: Alternative to `unsigned testchar=0; sscanf(&sit[i*2],"%02x",&testchar); recvalue[i]=(unsigned char)testchar;` -->  `sscanf(&sit[i*2],"%2hhx",&recvalue[i]);`

Comment: `hhx` would reflect better the value given. Thanks for the suggestion I've just checked in the man page and frankly didn't know it. Definitely no need for a temporary variable there as well... the less code the better!